# OpenCL producing incorrect calculations

Tags: python, opencl, gpgpu

I've been trying to use openCL to do some calculations, but the results are incorrect.

I input three float3's that look like this:

```
[300000,0,0]
[300000,300000,0]
[300000,300000,300000]
```

into this kernel:

```
__kernel void gravitate(__global const float3 *position,__global const float3 *momentum,__global const float3 *mass,__global float3 *newPosition,__global float3 *newMomentum,unsigned int numBodies,unsigned int seconds)
{
    int gid=get_global_id(0);

    newPosition[gid]=position[gid]*2;
    newMomentum[gid]=momentum[gid]*2;
}
```

I was originally trying to simulate the gravitational interaction of a group of bodies which is why the kernel looks like that.

For ouput I get:

```
[600000.0,0.0,0.0]
[x,600000.0,0.0]
[600000.0,x,600000.0]
```

Where x is a value that ranges from NaN to between 0 and 10^-44 and is different every time the kernel is run.
Both newPosition and newMomentum have the same incorrect output pattern.

The python code that I'm using looks like this:

```
def __init__(self):
        self.context=cl.create_some_context()
        self.queue=cl.CommandQueue(self.context)

        f=open("gravitate.cl")
        self.program=cl.Program(self.context,f.read()).build()

def simulate(self,seconds):
        bodyPosition=[]
        bodyMomentum=[]
        bodyMass=[]

        for body in self.objects:
            bodyPosition+=[body.position.x,body.position.y,body.position.z]
            bodyMomentum+=[body.momentum.x,body.momentum.y,body.momentum.z]
            bodyMass+=[body.mass]

        bodyPosition=numpy.array(bodyPosition).astype(numpy.float32)
        bodyMomentum=numpy.array(bodyMomentum).astype(numpy.float32)
        bodyMass=numpy.array(bodyMass).astype(numpy.float32)

        bodyPositionCl=cl.Buffer(self.context,cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY|cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR,hostbuf=bodyPosition)
        bodyMomentumCl=cl.Buffer(self.context,cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY|cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR,hostbuf=bodyMomentum)
        bodyMassCl=cl.Buffer(self.context,cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY|cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR,hostbuf=bodyMass)

        newBodyPosition=numpy.zeros(len(self.objects)*3).astype(numpy.float32)
        newBodyMomentum=numpy.zeros(len(self.objects)*3).astype(numpy.float32)

        newBodyPositionCl=cl.Buffer(self.context,cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY,newBodyPosition.nbytes)
        newBodyMomentumCl=cl.Buffer(self.context,cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY,newBodyMomentum.nbytes)

        self.program.gravitate(self.queue,(3,),None,bodyPositionCl,bodyMomentumCl,bodyMassCl,newBodyPositionCl,newBodyMomentumCl,numpy.uint32(len(self.objects)),numpy.uint32(seconds))
        cl.enqueue_read_buffer(self.queue,newBodyPositionCl,newBodyPosition).wait()
        cl.enqueue_read_buffer(self.queue,newBodyMomentumCl,newBodyMomentum).wait()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

float3 are 16-byte aligned. See OpenCL 1.1 spec, 6.1.5.